# How to write the code for viewing a word in the next line using XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xsd

I am customizing a report.While doing so i have faced a problem.the problem is the data is being viewed in column wise whereas it should be viewed row wise. Please help me in knowing what is the code to see to it that the words are being viewed on the next line.

say i am viewing it like the following

```
    abc def
```

Whereas I need to view it as

```
    abc
    def
```

what and how should i code?

Comment: The question itself may be nice. However, I think it has been answered on StackOverflow in many variances. Look for the keyword `tokenize`. If these answers don't fit you will definitely have to supply your coding attempts so far and tell us what the input XML looks like.

Comment: @MarcusRickert:i did not get what you meant??? if you are taking about my attempts i tried with the following `</br> </> <td><tr></tr></td>` i felt sharing this is not going to lead the answer.,.. so did not mention about it..... these are the 3 different methods i tried...i want to know if anything in **specific to XML**???

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: XML Schema won't help you. Schema is a way to describe the acceptable structure of a type of document. It has nothing to do with manipulating/exploring/rendering the document's content, except by providing semantic type information that other tools may use to help them do so.

XSLT might be more helpful to you -- but we'd need to know the actual structure of the XML data, not just its text content, to know what to look for in order to decide where line breaks occur. The problem is underspecified as it now stands.